# table width an bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with my table width in bootstrap, particularly when making it responsive.

I have a table, for example

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <% @list.each do |title| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= link_to title, :action => :topic, :title => title %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
    </table>
```

When I reduce my screen size, it doesn't get smaller like everything else and stay within the page, it just keeps going over the edge of the screen.  I have tried putting it in a container but this doesn't seem to help...

Comment: bootstrap-responsive.css file is included right??

Answer (score 1):

your mark up is wrong. you need a `<tbody>`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
 <tbody>
   <% @list.each do |title| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= link_to title, :action => :topic, :title => title %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```